# From String to java.security.PublicKey object gaves me an illegal character

Tags: java, base64, public-key

I have this method:

```
public static PublicKey getKey(String key){
    try{
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.getBytes());
        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        return kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This should transform a public key (one of n property in this JSON from [Salesforce public key endpoint](https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys)). In my keys should be kid 208, but:

```
getKey("pTSWJvy04hAU7ev7wmaTvpwHsEbseuPl0AlwoxPHnmoOIMATRT0eTqYpLJxDp4BHRFxDTrcUKHKVHGIAVut_-l6nkEI6ALOVW9C5PP9bXwqeHJ5tiGA6AMpaY1LsJJOd2lgExr0LHUPF2TtO4LOVmlptyGPTRSWhmRpPSc5bjGFsyTFr78WmeixjEts9icAUCiBDdpwVw9qVdjJPsufyimqp8os5htm-DB_qKsnRwABVSQRKLw2y7Mr7NP31R07Mpr108dLS5Et8tKnFoiX0MHf5BbA50NG3DtyT27nSa14T0IvSWYJQhxPWXYtuXkVldpbZZn8E2B1VpcDXXGnSPXoPstE9BU7w1RaF31UeEsE8sWDFdHgJMUYMfWjxVhdJB_NaVUt7v0X9QPffXcFPWKUUeVx0g_ONMz0bB_HltFSODWJeAvcZXk14u4sjpKXNIiK8dJzMe0Qn10m5nIdVtxzXfKHiDNobX1dMENDplhDMVk1eYS9x8dh90qt68Q59vKusm6iMjSaXtzwMfqJBwNck41e9Pie2m_cdSu-RIq1u3FScGkezzqNvIuzcse2y-6ApHkkaFMVsNw3CbD87LtVgNusuom38UVC1rS0LeLYFinU3hnFwvB1UCv1_0Cs8CmrOmdifqd25aZIDf5p8f3kowq3QY1mNtdQc9-HgZ3k");
```

returns me an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5f   at
>   java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)     at
>   java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)  at
>   testJwt.testJwt.App.getKey(App.java:52)   at
>   testJwt.testJwt.App.main(App.java:76)

What can I do? I'm do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you have is not the full RSA public key but rather just the modulus, or "n" value. The "e" value is the other part of the public key. Here is code fragment to illustrate it.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jsonN = "pTSWJvy04hAU7ev7wmaTvpwHsEbseuPl0AlwoxPHnmoOIMATRT0eTqYpLJxDp4BHRFxDTrcUKHKVHGIA" +
                "Vut_-l6nkEI6ALOVW9C5PP9bXwqeHJ5tiGA6AMpaY1LsJJOd2lgExr0LHUPF2TtO4LOVmlptyGPTRSWhmRpPSc5" +
                "bjGFsyTFr78WmeixjEts9icAUCiBDdpwVw9qVdjJPsufyimqp8os5htm-DB_qKsnRwABVSQRKLw2y7Mr7NP31R0" +
                "7Mpr108dLS5Et8tKnFoiX0MHf5BbA50NG3DtyT27nSa14T0IvSWYJQhxPWXYtuXkVldpbZZn8E2B1VpcDXXGnSP" +
                "XoPstE9BU7w1RaF31UeEsE8sWDFdHgJMUYMfWjxVhdJB_NaVUt7v0X9QPffXcFPWKUUeVx0g_ONMz0bB_HltFSO" +
                "DWJeAvcZXk14u4sjpKXNIiK8dJzMe0Qn10m5nIdVtxzXfKHiDNobX1dMENDplhDMVk1eYS9x8dh90qt68Q59vKu" +
                "sm6iMjSaXtzwMfqJBwNck41e9Pie2m_cdSu-RIq1u3FScGkezzqNvIuzcse2y-6ApHkkaFMVsNw3CbD87LtVgNu" +
                "suom38UVC1rS0LeLYFinU3hnFwvB1UCv1_0Cs8CmrOmdifqd25aZIDf5p8f3kowq3QY1mNtdQc9-HgZ3k";
        String jsonE = "AQAB";

        byte [] nBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(jsonN);
        byte [] eBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(jsonE);

        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, nBytes); // need to use the sign-magnitude constructor
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, eBytes);

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(n, e);
        KeyFactory rsaKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey rsaPub = rsaKeyFactory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
        System.out.println(rsaPub);
    }
}
```

Instead of doing this by hand I would look for a library that already does this, though library recommendations are off-topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have `_` and `-` in the Base64 string (instead of `/` and `+`). Then it is URL safe encoded Base64:

```
Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getBytes())
```

Comment: I thought too: but now I get `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format`

Comment: Inspect the resulting bytes, maybe they are normal Base64 or something.